# Como puedo cargar los datos a mi p-multiSelect?

Tags: angular, primeng

Hola gente estoy trabajando con el componente de primeNG , pero no logro cargar los datos.

[image: Imagen de productos vacios]

```js
this.listadoProductos = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listProduct'];
this.parametros['producto'] = this.listadoProductos;  
console.log(this.parametros['producto']);
```

```html
<!--MultiSelect-->
<h4>Grupo de producto</h4>
<div class="ui-fluid">
  <p-multiSelect  [options]="listadoProductos" [(ngModel)]="parametros.producto" optionLabel="descripcion"    defaultLabel="Producto" display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
</div>
```

Este es el objeto JSON que me devuelve en la consola.

[
[
1,
"Trigo                                             "
],
[
2,
"Maíz                                              "
],
[
3,
"Arroz                                             "
],
[
4,
"Otros granos                                      "
],
[
5,
"Aceites                                           "
],
[
6,
"Azúcar                                            "
]
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `[options]` del `[p-multiselect]` lo que tienes que pasarle es un array de objetos, no un array de arrays.

Por defecto el formato que espera de cada uno de estos objetos es el siguiente:

```
{
  value: //<- con el valor real de la opción,
  label: //<- con el texto a mostrar en la pantalla
}
```

Por lo que en tu caso entendiendo que en tu array, los números representan el value y el texto las labels, puedes conseguirlo mapeando el array que obtienes de la siguiente manera.

```
this.listadoProductos = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listProduct'].map(([value, label]) => ({value, label}))
```

un saludo